# ERC721 Conforming to Contract Standards

Tags: solidity, erc-721

When implementing the ERC721 contract standard, how strictly does one have to stick to the naming conventions of the method signatures - as spelled out by the standard?

Take for example the `ownerOf` function. The standard spells it out as follows:

```
function ownerOf(uint256 _tokenId) external view returns (address);
```

But what happens if I change the argument names when I implement this function in my contract?
For example:

```
function ownerOf(uint256 _creatureID) external view returns (addressOfOwner);
```

So instead of `_tokenId` I have `_creatureID` and instead of `address` I have `addressOfOwner`?

Does that negate the conformity? Will other platforms not be able to recognize and work with my contract because I made these changes? Or is it only the function's actual name - `ownerOf` - that matters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter names are not included in the specification.

You can confirm it is working correctly by using the `interface` included in the EIP and having your contract subclass (`is`) that.

But for `address`, that is a return type, not a name. So you might consider `address addressOfOwner`.